# How to update appsettings.json from wix custom actions with the values passed as parameter during command line installation?

Tags: c#, .net-core, wix, installation, custom-action

I’m currently working on a project where I am using `Wix` for the installer. My application is developed using `.net core` and having `appsettings.json` as a configuration file.

I would like to update the values on the `appsettings.json` with the values which passed as a parameter during `command-line installation`

For example, I am passing value `500` through parameter `BUFFER.SIZE`

```
msiexec.exe /i c:\PathToMyMsi\MyMsi.msi BUFFER.SIZE="500" /L*vx c:\PathToMyLog.txt
```

To achieve this, I have defined `property` and `custom action` in `Product.wxs` as follow

```
 <Property Id="BUFFER.SIZE" />

 <Binary Id="GetParameters.CA" SourceFile="..\..\Installer\CustomActions\bin\$(var.Configuration)\CustomActions.CA.dll" />
 <CustomAction Id="GetParValues" 
   BinaryKey="GetParameters.CA" 
   DllEntry="ConfigureBufferSize" 
   Execute="deferred" 
   Return="asyncWait" 
   Impersonate="no" />
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="GetParValues" After="InstallFiles"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Here is my custom action

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult ConfigureBufferSize(Session session)
    {
        try
        {
            session.Log("Begin ConfigureBufferSize");

            string size = "size = "+ session["BUFFER.SIZE"];
            session.Log(size); // I do not see any log like "size = 50"

            session.Log("End ConfigureBufferSize");
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }           
    }
```

But, I am stuck here because I am not able to read the values inside the custom function. the log does not contain below string

```
  "size = 500"
```

But, I see values in log as follow.

```
   MSI (c) (D0:54) [10:47:06:515]: Command Line: BUFFER.SIZE=500 
   CURRENTDIRECTORY=50 CLIENTUILEVEL=0 CLIENTPROCESSID=17360 
   MSI (s) (84:DC) [10:47:19:361]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding BUFFER.SIZE property. Its value is '500'.
   Property(C): BUFFER.SIZE = 500
```

How do I read these values in custom action and update the `appsettings.json`

I tried to use`Component` as follow but it's not executing post installation

```
  <Component Id="config" Guid="*">
    <File Id="appconfig" Source="$(var.BasePath)\appsettings.json" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes"/>
    <util:XmlFile
      Id="_pathFormat_" File="$(var.BasePath)\appsettings.json"
      Action="setValue"
      Name="pathFormat" Value="[BUFFER.SIZE]"
      ElementPath="/ApplicationLog/BufferSize"
      Sequence='1' />
  </Component>
```

Confused!!

**Update**

This is how I am able to get the passed values in custom actions

Declare a property

```
  <Property Id="BUFFER.SIZE"  Secure="yes"/>
```

Define the Binary

```
   <Binary Id="CustomActionDLL" SourceFile="..\..\Installer\CustomActions\CustomActions\bin\$(var.Configuration)\CustomActions.CA.dll" />
```

Define custom actions

```
 <CustomAction Id="SetGetParsValues"
              Property="GetParsValues"
              Value="BUFFER.SIZE=[BUFFER.SIZE]"/>
<CustomAction Id="GetParsValues"
              BinaryKey="CustomActionDLL"
              DllEntry="ConfigureBufferSize"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="check"
              Impersonate="no" />
```

Set up the installation sequence

```
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="GetParsValues" After="InstallFiles"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></Custom>
    <Custom Action="SetGetParsValues" Before="GetParsValues"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Now, I am able to see the passed parameters in the log.

But, when I try to pass `json` file path, it fails

```
     <Property Id="APPLICATION.PATH"  Secure="yes" Value="$(var.BasePath)\appsettings.json;"/>


 <CustomAction Id="SetFilePathID"
              Property="SetFilePath"
              Value="APPLICATION.PATH=[APPLICATION.PATH]"
              Return="check"/>
```

This fails.

Comment: Make sure to set `Secure="yes"` attribute for properties that should be used as command-line parameters. https://stackoverflow.com/a/889562/7571258

Comment: Also I would be surprised, if `util:XmlFile` works with JSON files.

Comment: @zett42 i better prefer updating app settings from custom actions. you can ignore util:XmlFile

Comment: @zett42 tried Secure="yes" but no luck.  any sample can be provided for above requirement?

Comment: `$(var.BasePath)\appsettings.json;` Firstly has a `;` at the end of it and I don't know what that will do. Secondly it looks like it might be pointing to the local path at build time and not the install path at runtime since you're using a $(var.BasePath) instead of [INSTALLDIR] or something like that. You can try running your install (installing or uninstalling) from the command line with `/l*v log.txt` to get a log file of your install or uninstall to see where it is crashing.

Comment: great catch, let me check those. also, is it possible to help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57373835/unable-to-uninstall-the-application-which-is-installed-using-wix-installer/57376073#57376073

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `session["BUFFER.SIZE"]` in a deferred custom action.

To pass a property from the MSI into a deferred custom action you need to use another action to set the value and then read that value in your custom action using a slightly different mechanism.

On the wixtoolset page for [custom action](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html) you'll see it has a special mention in the Property description pointing to [this microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/obtaining-context-information-for-deferred-execution-custom-actions) which talks about how getting context in a deferred custom action works.

An important thing to note about the second action is that its property value must be an exact match to the deferred custom action's Id value.

```
<CustomAction Id="SetGetParsValues" Property="GetParsValues" Value="BUFFER.SIZE=[BUFFER.SIZE]" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="SetGetParsValues" Before="GetParsValues"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

then in your custom action you can access the value by changing your `session["BUFFER.SIZE"]` to be `session.CustomActionData["BUFFER.SIZE"]`

It might also be useful for you to know about `[#FileId]` which gets evaluated as the install location of a component's File using the File's Id value. Then you can pass in two values to your custom action by updating the Value in the SetGetParsValues custom action to be `Value="BUFFER.SIZE=[BUFFER.SIZE];JsonFilePath=[#JsonFileId]"`. I'm not 100% sure doing `[#JsonFileId]` will work there so you can also just set a property value before that and use the property value in the Custom action's Value.